# array value by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an javascript array that has the following values,

```
let arr = ["2","4","6","8","10"];
```

I have a second array that has three integers,

```
let index = [1,5,9];
```

How would I use jQuery (or Javascript) to use the array to get the index from arr, and add it to a new array. I want to add these strings to a new array.

```
indexArr = ["1","3","5"]
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a very simple problem, easily solved by a map, and a toString function.

Comment: jQuery is for amending the DOM. There's no point using it on arrays. Also I don't see how either of the two arrays could possibly produce the content in the third one

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan very true. I had assumed that the OP just wanted to convert the values in `indexArr` to strings. Now I have no idea what they're asking.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no problems - I wasn't specifically referring to you :) I agree this question is confusing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = ["2","4","6","8","10"];
    var index =  ["1","5","9"];
    var arrIndex = index.map(function(value){
             return arr.indexOf(value);
    })

    console.log(arrIndex);
    })
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Instead, explain what your code does and how/why it may solve the question.